# Bash script fails to read entire file

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a bash script for backing up a set of folders/files. The script loops through a pre-configured file to determine how to copy the folder/file.

The problem I am facing is the script exits the while loop after processing the first "file" entry (2nd column value).

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo crontab -l > /home/ipaccess/crontab.txt

DATE=`date +%m-%d-%Y`

TARGETDIR="/exports/backup/Web-Server/$DATE/"
BACKUPLIST="/home/ipaccess/backup/backuplist"
ssh 172.29.32.246 mkdir -p $TARGETDIR
scp -r /home/ipaccess/crontab.txt 172.29.32.246:$TARGETDIR

cat $BACKUPLIST

while read dir type args
do
   echo "Processing [$dir $type $args]"
   echo "Directory: $dir"
   echo "Element type: $type"

   if [ $type = "folder" ] ; then
        echo "Source: $args"
        echo "Transfering $args to 172.29.32.246:$TARGETDIR$dir"
        scp -r $args 172.29.32.246:$TARGETDIR
   fi
   if [ $type = "file" ] ; then
        # Create folders first
        echo "Creating $TARGETDIR$dir"
        ssh 172.29.32.246 mkdir -p $TARGETDIR$dir
        scp $args 172.29.32.246:$TARGETDIR$dir
   fi
   echo "Finished processing $dir $type $args"
   echo "Next entry.."
done<$BACKUPLIST
echo "Backup complete."
```

Here is the pre-configured file (backuplist)

```
html/GS folder /var/www/html/GS/css
html/GS folder /var/www/html/GS/images
html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.html
html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.inc
html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.png
html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.mysql
html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/ac-db
html/HC file /var/www/html/HC/*.php
html/HC file /var/www/html/HC/*.html
html/HC file /var/www/html/HC/images
html/HC file /var/www/html/HC/PM/*.php
html/HC/PM file /var/www/html/HC/PM/jsapi
html/HourlyKpi file /var/www/html/HourlyKpi/*.php
html/KPI folder /var/www/html/KPI
html/KpiQuery folder /var/www/html/KpiQuery
html/wordpress/ folder /var/www/html/wordpress
usr/local/apache2/conf file /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
cgi-bin folder /var/www/cgi-bin
html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.php
```

Here is the output of the script

```
Processing [html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.html]
+ echo 'Directory: html/GS'
Directory: html/GS
+ echo 'Element type: file'
Element type: file
+ '[' file = folder ']'
+ '[' file = file ']'
+ echo 'Creating /exports/backup/Web-Server/04-18-2013/html/GS'
Creating /exports/backup/Web-Server/04-18-2013/html/GS
+ ssh 172.29.32.246 mkdir -p /exports/backup/Web-Server/04-18-2013/html/GS
+ scp /var/www/html/GS/gs.html /var/www/html/GS/login_header.html /var/www/html/GS/nologin_header.html /var/www/html/GS/overlaynal.html /var/www/html/GS/tab-test.html 172.29.32.246:/exports/backup/Web-Server/04-18-2013/html/GS
gs.html                                                                                            100% 3204     3.1KB/s   00:0
login_header.html                                                                                  100%  418     0.4KB/s   00:0
nologin_header.html                                                                                100%  464     0.5KB/s   00:0
overlay-external.html                                                                              100% 2308     2.3KB/s   00:0
tab-test.html                                                                                      100% 1573     1.5KB/s   00:0
+ echo 'Finished processing html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.html'
Finished processing html/GS file /var/www/html/GS/*.html
+ echo 'Next entry..'
Next entry..
+ read dir type args
+ echo 'Backup complete.'
Backup complete.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Nice first question.  I suspect that one of the commands in the body of the loop has eaten the rest of the lines in the `$BACKUPLIST` file as its standard input — probably the `ssh` command.  Not guaranteed, but plausible.  Try redirecting the input of `ssh` from `/dev/null` (and `scp` too).

Comment: I did read the FAQ before submitting my question :-) How do you redirect the input of ssh from /dev/null?

Comment: I am suspecting that something is consuming the rest of the file. Could it be related to the *.html in the file being read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `ssh` in your loop reads from standard input, even though the command you give it doesn't use the standard input. Use the `-n` option:

```
ssh -n 172.29.32.246 mkdir -p $TARGETDIR$dir
```

to redirect standard input from `/dev/null`.

Comment: This resolved the issue and now I have a complete backup script. Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 1):

Something inside the loop (almost certainly `ssh`) is reading the remainder of the file during the first loop. You can redirect `ssh`'s input (either with `< /dev/null` or its `-n` option), but it's slightly possible that something else in the loop will read from stdin (I don't *think* `scp` ever tries to read a password from stdin, but I could be wrong).

What I like to do in cases like this is to pass the file's contents to the `read` command via something other than stdin. I tend to use file descriptor #3 for this, since it's hardly ever used for anything else, and hence very unlikely that anything inside the loop will mess with it. To do this, just use `3<filename` to feed the file to fd3, and `read -u3` to read from it:

```
while read -u3 dir type args
do
    echo "Processing [$dir $type $args]"
    ...
done 3<$BACKUPLIST
```

Comment: +1 Good general purpose solution; this is the answer I would have posted, but I was feeling lazy and was recently reminded of the `-n` option to `ssh`.