# WHILE loop - read line of a file one by one -- Not working the No. of times the file has lines in it

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, while-loop, iteration

I'm using a "while" loop within a shell script (BASH) to read line of a file (one by one) -- "Fortunately", its not working the No. of times the file has lines in it.

Here's the summary:
$ cat inputfile.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now, the shell script content is pretty simple as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line 
do
 echo $line ----------; 
done < inputfile.txt;
```

The above script code works just fine..... :). It shows all the 5 lines from inputfile.txt.

Now, I have another script whose code is like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line 
do
 echo $line ----------;

 somevariable="$(ssh sshuser@sshserver "hostname")";
 echo $somevariable;
 
done < inputfile.txt;
```

Now, in this script, while loop just shows only line "1 ---------" and exits out from the loop after showing valid value for "$somevariable"

Any idea, what I'm missing here. I didn't try using some number N < inputfile.txt and using done <&N way (i.e. to change the input redirector by using a file pointed by N descriptor)
.... but I'm curious why this simple script is not working for N no. of times, when I just added a simple variable declaration which is doing a "ssh" operation in a child shell.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that your return value `$somevariable` contains an EOF type marker (^D)?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094925/bash-script-fails-to-read-entire-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094925/bash-script-fails-to-read-entire-file)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to add the `-n` option to the ssh command. This would prevent it to "swallow" your inputfile.txt as its standard input.

Alternatively, you might just redirect ssh stdin from /dev/null, eg:

```
somevariable="$(ssh sshuser@sshserver "hostname" </dev/null)";
```

Comment: that seems likely. Your ssh session is sharing stdin with the while loop. Note that a bash loop that is redirected like this becomes a new process with its own stdin/stdout etc streams - so that you can then redirect them.

Comment: @rivimey: it doesn't become a new process. The while loop is executed by the same shell.